# Is there a way to see if an rpm was installed manually or installed from a repo?

Tags: yum, rpm

Title pretty much sums it up, but I'm looking for an rpm or yum command to see if an installed package was installed from the repos (if repo, which repo?), or manually.

Comment: See: [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/62026/how-to-know-from-which-yum-repository-a-package-has-been-installed) and [this question](http://serverfault.com/questions/355836/how-can-i-tell-what-rpms-are-managed-outside-of-yum) for a starting point

Comment: Totally misread the question, doh. Deleting my answer. Seems like Janne Pikkarainen's answer in @cyberx86 first suggestion would work for you.

Comment: [Janne Pikkarainen](http://serverfault.com/users/49773/janne-pikkarainen)'s [answer](http://serverfault.com/a/356162/8263) is in the second question.

Comment: What version of RPM and YUM are you using? Running YUM 3.2.22-37 and RPM 4.4.2.3-22 (RHEL 5) doesn't show the `From Repo` line mentioned by Janne. You could try checking `/var/log/yum.log*` files for an RPM; if it's not there it was not installed by YUM. Watch out for initial installs, though: things installed from CDROM won't be in the YUM logs I don't think.

Answer (score 0):

rpm -qai |grep

example:

```
rpm -qai |grep -9 wget
restore individual files (or all of the files) from that archive. Tar
can also be used to add supplemental files to an archive and to update
or list files in the archive. Tar includes multivolume support,
automatic archive compression/decompression, the ability to perform
remote archives, and the ability to perform incremental and full
backups.

If you want to use tar for remote backups, you also need to install
the rmt package.
Name        : wget                         Relocations: (not relocatable)
Version     : 1.12                              Vendor: CentOS
Release     : 1.4.el6                       Build Date: Wed Aug 25 04:53:32 2010
Install Date: Sun Jul 10 18:23:54 2011         Build Host: c6b3.bsys.dev.centos.org
Group       : Applications/Internet         Source RPM: wget-1.12-1.4.el6.src.rpm
Size        : 1877597                          License: GPLv3+ and GFDL
Signature   : RSA/8, Sun Jul  3 01:05:14 2011, Key ID 0946fca2c105b9de
Packager    : CentOS BuildSystem <http://bugs.centos.org>
URL         : http://wget.sunsite.dk/
Summary     : A utility for retrieving files using the HTTP or FTP protocols
Description :
GNU Wget is a file retrieval utility which can use either the HTTP or
FTP protocols. Wget features include the ability to work in the
background while you are logged out, recursive retrieval of
directories, file name wildcard matching, remote file timestamp
storage and comparison, use of Rest with FTP servers and Range with
HTTP servers to retrieve files over slow or unstable connections,
support for Proxy servers, and configurability.
```

Comment: that's a dirty grep but i added the -9 so you could see the entire wget entry, there is probably another flag to just show for one package

Comment: Use the package name (`rpm -qa` for a list) instead of grep: `rpm -qi wget`